# MySQL: errno: 150 on foregin key asignment

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a foreign key to a table and I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'tablename.#sql-5cf_179' (errno: 150)
```

I use this query:

```
alter table table_1 add foreign key (col_1) references table_2 (col_2);
```

Both columns have the same datatype (varchar(50)), same collation, they're not null and I changed the default value to something different from null too.

I checked SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and got this:

> Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the referenced
>   columns appear as the first columns, or column types in the table and
>   the referenced table do not match for constraint. Note that the
>   internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in tables created with
>
> > = InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables. See
> >     http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
> >     for correct foreign key definition.

I have no idea what do to next...

EDIT more info added:

```
    |snmptt_nodes | CREATE TABLE `snmptt_nodes` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no_ip_found',
      `last_response` datetime NOT NULL,
      `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 

| snmptt | CREATE TABLE `snmptt` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventname` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventid` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trapoid` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `enterprise` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `community` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hostname` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `agentip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no_ip_found',
  `category` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `severity` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uptime` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `traptime` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `formatline` varchar(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=206352 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

| snmptt_listpolls | CREATE TABLE `snmptt_listpolls` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no_ip_found',
  `polling_time` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `communitydata` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `snmp_oid` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastcheck` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Can you show the CREATE TABLE for the two tables in question.

Comment: Well, both tables exist already so I'm using ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Oh, I  meant `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. That will allow you to see the structure of your tables. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: Those are the three tables I want to use. I want to have a foreign key for the table snmptt_nodes to the other two. The foreign key should be the ip.

Comment: Please edit to show your actual `ALTER TABLE` statement so we can see which columns are truly being referenced. The error indicates that you are attempting to reference a column without an index. For a FK constraint to succeed, the referenced column _must_ have an index (or compound index works in some circumstances). Most often, it's a primary key and the requirement is fulfilled. Yours sounds like it is not referencing a PK though, so another index is needed.

Comment: Ok, that might be you problem. A column can only foreign key to on column. That is: `snmptt_nodes.ip` cannot foreign key to bother `snmptt.agentip` and `snmptt_listpolls.ip`. Also "MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys". Read over this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: One of them is: alter table snmptt add foreign key (agentip) references snmptt_nodes (ip);

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is create a trigger that when data is inserted into the listpolls compares timestamps and depending on the output it will insert a different name into another column, so I think the table should be linked by foreign keys.

Comment: That means you must first add an index to `snmptt_nodes.ip`. If it is a unique value, then consider just making that the primary key instead of including the auto-incrementing `ID`.

Comment: Well, yeah, I think it could be a unique value, I will check that first.

Comment: Starting with `ALTER TABLE snmptt_nodes ADD UNIQUE INDEX (ip);` should work for the FK definition you listed.

Comment: And in fact it does: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8009a  All tables are created, the index is added, then the FK constraint is successfully created.